# Cannot import imaging from PIL

Tags: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/raghav/Desktop/Everything/TinderAutomation-master/img_scrape.py", line 1, in <module>
    from skimage.io import imread, imsave, imshow, show
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/skimage/io/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .manage_plugins import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/skimage/io/manage_plugins.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .collection import imread_collection_wrapper
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/skimage/io/collection.py", line 11, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 60, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/__init__.py)
```

I've problem importing imaging modules like matplotlib and skimage.io. I'm fairly new to python. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: usually modules starting with underscore are compiled C modules, and failing to import it could mean that you don't have a version that is compiled suitably for your hardware. How did you install PIL?

Comment: Those file paths look like you've got multiple Python versions mixed up. One Python installation is trying to import modules out of a different Python installation, and that doesn't work.

Comment: Relevant [`"cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL'"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22cannot+import+name+%27_imaging%27+from+%27PIL%27%22)

Answer (score -1):

Try this: I first installed PIL (not Pillow) using

```
pip3 install --no-index -f https://dist.plone.org/thirdparty/ -U PIL
```

Then I found Pillow and installed it using

```
pip3 install Pillow
```

What fixed my issues was uninstalling both and reinstalling Pillow

```
pip3 uninstall PIL
pip3 uninstall Pillow
pip3 install Pillow
```